# I don't need django tables by default

Tags: python, django, django-models

Here is my question, I have to do a new django project but I don't need the database tables that django offers by default, auth_user, table... etc. Is there any way for start a project synchronizing the database but without all this stuff?

I have tried to comment the INSTALLED_APPS by default and MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES but it retrieves me errors or issues.

Comment: Could you post the error messages? Thanks

Comment: Please post the error message on the question. :). I cannot see them all on the comment section.

Comment: These are the commented lines and then in the terminal retrives this error: "admin.LogEntry.user(fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model auth.User, which is either not installed or is abstract"

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    #'django.contrib.auth',
    #'django.contrib.sessions',
    #'django.contrib.messages'
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    #'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    #'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    #'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    #'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

Comment: I have discovered where the mistake was, I had to disable the admin urls too and then I could disable all of the rest. (I don't need the admin panel too)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I have finally discoved how to disable all of this tables and disable the admin if you don't need it.

You have to disable in INSTALLED_APPS:

```
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
```

and in the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:

```
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware'
```

and make sure that you have disabled the admin urls.

Thanks everyone for answering.

Answer (score 3):

Just don't include (or comment out) the middleware or apps that you don't need. While the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` setting is required to be present...it doesn't need to contain the authentication middleware.

In other words, keep `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` and `INSTALLED_APPS` in your **settings.py**, but remove the middleware classes and apps that you don't need.

Comment: I kept it (MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES and INSTALLED_APPS), but when I comment for example: auth, sessions and admin and their respective middleware classes it retrives me an error: " 
The session-based temporary message storage requires session middleware to be installed, and come before the message middleware in the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES list."

Comment: You need to also comment out `'django.contrib.messages'` and `'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware'`. You can't use messages without sessions enabled.

Comment: It retrives me this error "Put 'django.contrib.admin' in your INSTALLED_APPS setting in order to use the admin application." but I don't need the admin panel, at least I think I will allow django create all the tables and then won't use these tables.

Comment: @rnevius not entirely true: you can set `MESSAGE_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.messages.storage.cookie.CookieStorage'` to use cookies if you want messages without sessions. Messages would be limited to 2K though.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, have a look at the django docs [Legacy Databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/legacy-databases/) section. Also disable the middleware and apps you don't need in your `settings.py`.

With `inspect_db` you can connect to your existing database and get a full manageable `models.py` out of it. Then, just create your own `views.py` and add it to your `INSTALLED_APPS`.